# Error in Execute SQL Task when Updating Master Table comparing with Temp Table in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have separated Matching rows with **Lookup** and stored the matched data into a temp table through **ODLEDB Destination**.

After finishing data flow task its getting error on ***Execute SQL Task***.

*Property was set as*
`ResultSet: "NONE";

ConnectionType:"OLEDB";

Connection:"myDatabase";

SQLType: "Direct Input"`

***SQLStatement***

```
Update dbo.[Payment_Transaction] 
SET pt.[Date] = tt.[Date], pt.[FromCurrency]=tt.FromCurrency], pt.[ToCurrency]=tt.[ToCurrency], pt.[TransRate]=tt.[TransRate], pt.[TransType] =tt.[TransType], pt.[TransAmount]=tt.[TransAmount] 
FROM dbo.[Payment_Transaction] pt INNER JOIN  [##temp_table] tt ON pt.[ID] = tt.[ID]
```

Getting **ERROR** saying
 `"Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly"`.

Can anyone please shade any light where it could be wring?

Thanks,

Jahid

Comment: what is [##temp_table] ? was it created on any of the previous steps ?

Comment: Have you tried executing all the statements just in SSMS ? If everything is working correct, you can try configuring Sql Server Log in order to get the full error description.    I am suspecting that your global temp table is deleted when you are trying to join it. In order to prevent this, you can try setting RetainSameConnection to true property for your Connection manager

Comment: I think this answer may help you, if Mario's suggestion doesn't work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51769262/1169697

Answer (score 0):

Hi I guess is tmp table related so...
try with  "Set RetainSameConnection=TRUE on the connection manager and set DelayValidation=TRUE on all tasks that use the temp table. Setting RetainSameConnection=TRUE ensures that the temp table does not disappear when the task that creates it has completed. Setting DelayValidation=TRUE ensures that the tasks do not try to check that the table exists before it is created."

http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2006/11/19/SSIS_3A00_-Using-temporary-tables.aspx

Cheers, Mario