# Temp Table created in one Execute SQL Task is not available in another Execute SQL Task in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I created one Global Temp Table in one Execute SQL Task and the inserted some records into that table. While calling the result in another Execute SQL Task it is saying invalid object name.

Please suggest

Thanks
Sasi

Comment: You cannot refer to a temp table in another Execute SQL Task. Then you have to make a real persisted table.

Comment: Show your code on how you create your temptable. And how you call it in the second sql task

Comment: I created a ##temp1 in one execute sql task and in another execute sql task i am doing like (insert into ##temp1 select * from mytable) the error is invalid object ##temp1 in second execute sql task

Comment: Yes that is because its not related to the same transaction. So either you go for a persisted table or else you try userfl89's solution

Answer (score 1):

If you put both Execute SQL Tasks in the same Sequence Container and set the `TransactionOption` to `Required` on the Sequence Container you can access the global temp table from the second Execute SQL Task.  You can leave the `TransactionOption` at the default of `Supported` for both Execute SQL Tasks, as they will join the transaction of the parent Sequence Container.

Comment: I am getting the below error
Error: The SSIS Runtime has failed to start the distributed transaction due to error 0x8004D01B "The Transaction Manager is not available.". The DTC transaction failed to start. This could occur because the MSDTC Service is not running.

Comment: Is the MS DTC service currently running?  You can check this by going to Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services > then find the Distributed Transaction Coordinator service, and start it if it's not running.

Comment: It is solved by using retain same connection true in connection manager

Answer (score 0):

The lifespan of a temp table is constricted to the Task it is associated with, so you wont be able to access it like this.
You'll have to create a more permanent solution, or handle it in a way like userfl89 above stated.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using  Retain same connection = true in Connection Manager

thanks
Sasi